# reject: RCPT from unknown[]: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your reverse hostname

Tags: postfix, hostname, smtpd

Sending an email from my local network is going fine. Also through Thunderbird or remote with Roundcube, which is locally installed.
But now, I am in Asia and try to send an email with Thunderbird.
The following error is in the log:

```
postfix/submission/smtpd[4588]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[110.170.163.146]: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your reverse hostname, [110.170.163.146]; from=<<me>@<mydomain.com>> to=<<me>@<mydomain.co>> proto=ESMTP helo=<[10.10.3.55]>
```

dig +short -t A mail.<mydomain.com> gives: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, the IP of my server.

dig +short -x 110.170.163.146 gives: 110-170-163-146.static.asianet.co.th.
Here you can see, I am now in Thailand.

In Thunderbird I have:

```
Server Name: mail.<mydomain.com>
Port: 587
Connection security: STARTTLS
Authentication method: Normal password
Username: <me>@<mydomain.com>
```

All smtpd lines in master.cf:

```
submission     inet     n    -    y    -    -    smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=no
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=inet:10.89.0.10:12345
```

All smtpd rules in main.cf:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.<mydomain.com>/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.<mydomain.com>/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = inet:dovecot:12345
reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/spfcheck check_sender_access /etc/postfix/sender_access check_recipient_access /etc/postfix/recipient_access
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/spfcheck
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated,
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_helo_hostname
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname
```

As far as I can tell, the error message is "reverse hostname" related. I am outside my normal hostname. But Thunderbird should log in and still send the email.

Anyone any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: I edited a presumed copy-paste mistake in your question. If I was wrong, and that was an actual syntax error in your file, check that. For the future, I recommend you always review configuration using the commands `postconf -n` and `postconf -M` - not only will that always produce well-formatted output, it will also help identify differences between intended and effective configuration rooted in syntax problems.

Comment: Nice options!. I do regularly postfix reload and check, but (see below). But sometimes i forget.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is happening is that your `submission` service is inheriting the `main.cf` options. Those deviations from the postfix defaults may not be unreasonable for server to server mail exchange. But for clients connecting from just about anywhere (not through fixed uplinks or VPN), a resolvable reverse name not be expected.

It also is unnecessary to demand *both* reverse name and sasl. The name submitted during authentication serves as a much more useful identifier anyway (unique, locally administered, verified).

Suggested fix: Override the relevant option for the authentication-only port(s) in your master.cf, as is already done with the restriction set demanding authentication:

```
submission     inet     n    -    y    -    -    smtpd
  -o ...
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
  -o ...
  -o ...
```

After making changes, reload configuration (depending on distribution, something like `systemctl reload postfix`) and check logs produced during startup.

Comment: Thanks!. I needed to add the "-o smtpd_client_restrictions=" to the master.cf AND change it in main.cf to also an "smtpd_client_restrictions=". But now I can send emails from Asia.
Edit: I have not enough points to upvote your answer (yet).

Comment: I would not recommend changing the main.cf settings (presumably applied to the usual server to server exchanges) while working on an MUA-only problem. It is an unrelated piece of policy, and if it has worked well for you before, why relax those requirements now?

Comment: I restored the main.cf. Probably I forgot to do "postfix reload" or something.